# How is Java jitting inefficient code to run faster than efficient code?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jvm, jit

In the following code snippet, `Foo1` is a class that increments a counter every time the method `bar()` is called. `Foo2` does the same thing but with one additional level of indirection.

I would expect `Foo1` to be faster than `Foo2`, however in practice, `Foo2` is consistently 40% faster than `Foo1`. How is the JVM optimizing the code such that `Foo2` runs faster than `Foo1`?

#### Some Details

- The test was executed with `java -server CompositionTest`.
- Running the test with `java -client CompositionTest` produces the expected results, that `Foo2` is slower than `Foo1`.
- Switching the order of the loops does not make a difference.
- The results were verified with java6 on both sun and openjdk's JVMs.

#### The Code

```
public class CompositionTest {

    private static interface DoesBar {
        public void bar();
        public int count();
        public void count(int c);
    }

    private static final class Foo1 implements DoesBar {
        private int count = 0;
        public final void bar() { ++count; }
        public int count() { return count; }
        public void count(int c) { count = c; }
    }

    private static final class Foo2 implements DoesBar {
        private DoesBar bar;
        public Foo2(DoesBar bar) { this.bar = bar; }
        public final void bar() { bar.bar(); }
        public int count() { return bar.count(); }
        public void count(int c) { bar.count(c); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = 0;
        DoesBar bar = null;
        int reps = 100000000;

        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
            bar = new Foo1();
            bar.count(0);

            int i = reps;
            time = System.nanoTime();
            while (i-- > 0) bar.bar();
            time = System.nanoTime() - time;

            if (reps != bar.count())
                throw new Error("reps != bar.count()");
        }
        System.out.println("Foo1 time: " + time);

        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
            bar = new Foo2(new Foo1());
            bar.count(0);

            int i = reps;
            time = System.nanoTime();
            while (i-- > 0) bar.bar();
            time = System.nanoTime() - time;

            if (reps != bar.count())
                throw new Error("reps != bar.count()");
        }
        System.out.println("Foo2 time: " + time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try switching the loops to see if it made a difference?

Comment: It might be a good idea to read a good SO post about [Java microbenchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) and then review your code to make sure your results are actually meaningful.

Comment: I tried it (with JRE7 -server) and it did not make a difference. Whaaat?! I know it should, that the JRE need to warm up and compile the code, but ... it doesn't make a difference. At all.

Comment: Wow. Great question. I found that if you add up the time taken overall (rather than just measuring the count of the final loop), that the two methods are much closer (although strangely with foo2 being around 2% faster). As to the reason, ?

Comment: @AHungerArtist: Switching the order of the loops does not make a difference.

Comment: @Chris: Just looking at the last measurement allows the JVM to "warm-up" the code. The first few runs of the code are interpreted whereas the later runs of the code will be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to predict performance on modern languages is not very productive.

The JVM is constantly modified to increase performance of common, readable structures which, in contrast, makes uncommon, awkward code slower.

Just write your code as clearly as you can--then if you really identify a point where your code is actually identified as too slow to pass written specifications, you may have to hand-tweak some areas--but this will probably involve large, simple ideas like object caches, tweaking JVM options and eliminating truly stupid/wrong code (Wrong data structures can be HUGE, I once changed an ArrayList to a LinkedList and reduced an operation from 10 minutes to 5 seconds, multi-threading a ping operation that discovered a class-B network took an operation from 8+ hours to minutes).

Comment: I'm simply trying to understand the behaviour of the JVM. In this case, I'm just curious about how the JVM handles such levels of indirection. This isn't _premature optimization_. I simply want to understand how code that I write is interpreted by the jit compiler.

Comment: @TianyuZhu I totally understand, I guess I'd say that the behavior of the JVM is to change and adapt--so ever trying to USE your current knowledge of the JVM to increase speed is a bad thing--but learning about it is always fun.

Answer (score 2):

Your microbench mark is meaningless. On my computer the code runs in about 8ms for each loop... To have any meaningful number a benchmark should probably run for at least a second.

When run both for around a second (hint, you need more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` repetitions) I find that the run times of both are identical.

The likely explanation for this is that the JIT compiler has noticed that your indirection is meaningless and optimised it out (or at least inlined the method calls) such that the code executed in both loops is identical.

It can do this because it knows `bar` in `Foo2` is effectively final, it also know that the argument to the `Foo2` constructor is always going to be a `Foo1` (at least in our little test). That way it knows the exact code path when `Foo2.bar` is called. It also knows that this loop is going to run a lot of times (in fact it knows exactly how many times the loop will execute) -- so it seems like a good idea to inline the code.

I have no idea if that is precisely what it does, but these are all logical observations that the JIT could me making about the code. Perhaps in the future some JIT compilers might even optimise the entire while loop and simply set count to reps, but that seems somewhat unlikely.

Comment: You're computer must be pretty fast. I suggest you change `reps` from `int` to `long` and retry with `Long.MAX_VALUE` reps.

Comment: I have an i3... I converted your code to C++ where it takes a **lot** longer (13 seconds for `Foo1` and 22 seconds for `Foo2`) when using `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. For the java version, if I do something as simple as changing the type of `i` to long (not the value, just the type), the execution time is now about 3 seconds. As someone else said, micro benchmarking is never a good idea on Java.